# Book published in 1980's - college student that absorbs a "crystalline" alien

Tags: story-identification, cryogenics

Book I read when I was younger, that had the key character as a college student that was a perpetual student whose costs were covered by an uncle that was put in cryostasis. As long as the kid was a full-time student, the frozen uncle paid the bill. 
Kid falls asleep at a party with some friends and apparently has a "crystal" that disappears, and he starts hearing things. If memory serves it was rhymes such as "do you hear me fred" and other such as that.

Comment: If the question has been answered to your satisfaction, you can [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 10):

**Book I read when I was younger,**

[*Doorways in the Sand*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2082), a 1976 novel by [Roger Zelazny](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?69).

**that had the key character as a college student that was a perpetual student whose costs were covered by an uncle that was put in cryostasis. As long as the kid was a full-time student, the frozen uncle paid the bill.**

From the [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doorways_in_the_Sand):

> The will of Fred Cassidy’s cryogenically-frozen uncle provides him with a generous stipend to attend the university until he is awarded an academic degree. By carefully choosing his courses and changing majors, Fred avoids mandatory graduation for thirteen years. He meets with his new academic counselor, Dennis Wexroth, who is infuriated by what he calls Fred’s “dronehood” and threatens to send him off into to the real world by graduating Fred in the coming semester. Fred, however, finds a way to get enough credits in different majors to avoid graduation.

**Kid falls asleep at a party with some friends and apparently has a "crystal" that disappears, and he starts hearing things.**

The [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doorways_in_the_Sand) continues:

> Fred goes to his apartment and finds it ransacked. He examines the apartment, but finds nothing missing. Paul Byler, Fred’s geology teacher comes out of a closet. He slaps Fred around demanding the return of a replica he made of the crystalline star-stone. Byler is a world-renowned expert in crystallography and says he makes copies of the star-stone in order to sell them as novelty items. Fred states that the replica is not in the apartment and maybe his ex-roommate has it. Byler does not believe Fred. After a brief fight Fred escapes through a window to an outside ledge.

**If memory serves it was rhymes such as "do you hear me fred" and other such as that.**

The beginning of the novel:

> Lying, left hand for a pillow, on the shingled slant of the roof, there in the shade of the gable, staring at the cloud-curdles in afternoon's blue pool, I seemed to see, between blinks, above the campus and myself, an instant piece of sky-writing:
>
> DO YOU SMELL ME DED? I read.

From chapter 2:

> Walking past a darkened bakery. Play of night and light on glass. DO YOU TASTE ME BRED? I read. I hesitated, turned, saw where shadows had anagrammatized a bake sale, sniffed, hurried on.

From chapter 3:

> Flashes and imaginings . . . "Do you hear me, Fred? Do you hear me, Fred?" Water, trickling down my throat. Another blackness. Flash. Water, on my face, in my mouth. Movement. Shadows. A moaning . . .
>
> Moaning. Shadows, a lesser black. Flash. Flashes. A light through parted lashes, dim. The ground below, passing. The moaning, mine.
>
> "Do you hear me, Fred?"
>
> "Yes," I said, "yes . . ."
>
> The movement ceased. I overheard an exchange in a language I did not recognize. Then the ground rose. I was deposited upon it.
>
> "Are you awake? Can you hear me?"
>
> "Yes, yes. I already said 'yes.' How many times—"
>
> "Yes, he appears to be awake"—this superfluous comment in a voice that I recognized as that of my friend the wombat.

Comment: As I recall it ends with him saving the world and being graduated. When he objects he is informed that he was granted a PHD for a paper that he wrote. None of the members of the PHD committee could bring themselves to object as he had taught them all.

Comment: Interestingly, the set-up reminded me of Victor Tugelbend from Terry Pratchett's novel *Moving Pictures* (1990), and looking into that I learned that the character of Grimsdyke in Richard Gordon's *Doctor in the House*  (1952) predates both Pratchett and Zelazny but he, too, is the recipient of a sum of money as long as he remains a student, and pulls the same trick of just barely failing each year.